# How to return value of asynchronous function and use outside of scope in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

All I basically want to do is to be able to use the return value from an asynchronous function. I assumed the variable tag (in the code below) would contain the return value from the async function but it rather contains the response. How could I possibly get hold of the return value from the aRes function into a variable that I can use outside the scope of the async function. Thank you in advance.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = "someurl.com"

//async function to be passed to http.get as second parameter
function aRes(response){
    var newtag = response.headers.etag;
    return newtag;
}

var tag = http.get(url,aRes);
console.log(tag); //logs the response from get request

//tag is not the return value from the ares function but rather the response object. How do I get the return value of that?
```

Comment: learn about callbacks and/or promises - basically, you need to learn how to code for the asynchronous nature of asynchronous functions

Comment: There are hundreds of dups of this question.  The answer in a nushell is that you can't return an async value.

Answer (score 0):

Use callback. Or better yet use Promise (recommend trying out `bluebird`), your code will look easier to read.

You can do something like below with `request` library after promisify it.

```
request.getAsync(url)
.spread(yourFunction)
```

`yourFunction` will take args from `requestAsync`.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own callback function:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = "someurl.com";

var aResCallback = function(tag) {
    console.log(tag); //logs the response from get request
};

//async function to be passed to http.get as second parameter
function aRes(response){
    var newtag = response.headers.etag;
    aResCallback(newtag);
    return newtag;
}

var tag = http.get(url, aRes);
```